# Async await, how to use them in a windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await, ado.net

```
string DBconnString = 
  "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + Para1 + @"\Labo_be.mdb;";

var DBConn = new OleDbConnection(DBconnString);
DBConn.Open();

string S_Query = "Select * FROM DISEGNI";
cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(S_Query, DBConn);
DR = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while (DR.Read())
{
    var sName = DR.GetString(DR.GetOrdinal("PARTNBR"));
    Combo_Dis.Items.Add(sName);
}
```

How to transform this sub using `async await`?
This sub loads a combo with more than **35000** drawing numbers so the app is **very very slow**.

Comment: You don't want have 35000 entries in the combobox, do you?

Comment: After re-reading the question, and out of curiosity, what was your expectation of async await to solve in this particular case? loading so many records will of course has a side effect !

Comment: @MaythamFahmi I'm sure it's a duplicate of something but the answer to the question you linked is just wrong.

Comment: Read this Microsoft article and you will know the answers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/asynchronous-programming#see-also

Comment: You could use [Dapper QueryAsync](https://www.learndapper.com/dapper-query/selecting-multiple-rows#dapper-queryasync). Very simple to use.

Comment: If you think that be making your code asynchronous you'll also make it run faster, you are up for a disappointment. Asynchronous programming is intended for optimizing memory, be making efficient use of threads. Unless you are running short on memory, don't expect any speed improvement.

Comment: You need to make your method `async` and then call the Async versions of the ADO.NET methods like `ExecuteReaderAsync()` and `ReadAsync()`. Using async methods will prevent the UI to freeze but will not speed up the loading.

Comment: @KlausGütter, my user wants to have the possibility to choose, but if a less number of drawing can solve the problem...but the table associated still have more than 35000 records.Or there is a control more useful than the combobox to display records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use *WinForms* it is `Combo_Dis.Items.Add` in a *loop* that is that slow (about *5 seconds* on my workstation): when you add a new item, combo box should do some computations (dropdown size), redraw itself etc. You can use `BeginUpdate() .. EndUpdate()` to do this extra work just *once*:

```
using var DBConn = new OleDbConnection(
  $"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={Path.Combine(Para1, Labo_be.mdb)};"); 

DBConn.Open();

string S_Query = 
  @"SELECT PARTNBR 
      FROM DISEGNI";

using var cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(S_Query, DBConn);

using var dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

Combo_Dis.BeginUpdate();

try {
  while (dr.Read()) {
    Combo_Dis.Items.Add(dr[0]);
  }
}
finally {
  Combo_Dis.EndUpdate();
}
```

Comment: @dmitribychenko, GREAT! Now on my workstation the time for showing the windows is decreased to about 2-3 seconds! Many thanks!!!!!